# Get continuous input from pipe in C++

Tags: c++, pipe

I have a simple script to echo data and I want to pipe the data to other program.

For example

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "1st line of data"
sleep $(($RANDOM % 10))
echo "2nd line of data"
sleep $(($RANDOM % 10))
echo "3rd line of data"
sleep $(($RANDOM % 10))
echo "4th line of data"
sleep $(($RANDOM % 10))
echo "5th line of data"
sleep $(($RANDOM % 10))
echo "6th line of data"
sleep $(($RANDOM % 10))
echo "7th line of data"
sleep $(($RANDOM % 10))
echo "8th line of data"
```

Then

```
sh echo_data.sh | ./parse_data
```

How I get the data in C++?

Comment: You read the data from standard input stream, aka `std::cin` or `stdin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it from `stdin`.

```
std::string line;
while (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
    // parse line
}
```

Comment: That script in only and example. I have a program wich doesn't stop echoing until it isn't stopped. With your code if it doesn't recive any data it will stop the loop, I need to keep the loop running.

Should I do this?
 while(true){
  if(std::getline(std::cin, line)){
   //parse line
  }
 }

Comment: The loop terminates only when it reads an EOF, or it meets some error. If it doesn't receive any data, the program just blocks there, waiting for input from `stdin`.

Comment: So it only stops when `echo_data.sh` is closed?

Comment: When 'echo_data.sh' terminates, `getline` will read an EOF, and the loop will terminate. However, if you close `stdin` in your script before exiting, the loop in your c++ code will terminate immediately.